# Validating a simple login using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, validation, authentication, forms-authentication

I have a datasource using LINQ where I need to validate a simple user, password against.

```
//load textfields to local variables
        string User = UserName.Text.ToLower().Trim();
        string Pass = UserPass.Text.ToLower().Trim();

        //Check Credentials
        var xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm");
        var Inspectors = from i in xrm.SystemUserSet
                         where i.new_MobileAppUser.Equals(User.ToString())
                         select new { InspectorPass = i.new_MobileAppPassword 
                         };

        if (User == null || Pass == null)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "You must enter a valid username and password"; 
        }

        if (Inspectors == Pass)
            {
                // do something (correct password)
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, chkPersistCookie.Checked);
                Response.Redirect("/default.aspx"); 
            }
            else
            {
                // something else (incorrect password)
            lblMsg.Text = "Sorry, Invalid credentials. Please try again."; 
            }
```

Is there something I'm missing here? I've followed other peoples examples and I should be able to if inspectors == Pass then redirect. But it's complaining that I cannot?

Error Message:-

> Error Error   23  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' and 'string'    logon.aspx.cs

Comment: Error
Error 23 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' and 'string' logon.aspx.cs 43 17

Comment: Same error message if I change Inspectors.SingleOrDefault() == Pass

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    var inspector = Inspectors.SingleOrDefault();
    if(inspector != null && inspector.InspectorPass == Pass)
    {}
}
catch(){}
```

Comment: Isn't adding the SingleOrDefault() trying to match a char?

Comment: You can find answer to your question trying the code above :)

Comment: I changed the IF statement to
if (Inspectors.FirstOrDefault().InspectorPass == Pass) and worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` is preferred in you scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just fetching single property you don't need `anonymous type`. Also, you need to fetch a single `new_MobileAppPassword` because currently it is returing a collection `IQueryable<T>` and that is the cause of your error:-

```
var Inspectors = (from i in xrm.SystemUserSet
                  where i.new_MobileAppUser.Equals(User.ToString())
                  select i.new_MobileAppPassword).FirstOrDefault();
```

But remember it will return null if it doesn't have any matching user so you need to handle that.

Comment: Same error message - unless I change the line

   if (Inspectors.ToString() == Pass) 

But then it always goes to the else. I know the credentials are correct as I can see them in the backend.

Comment: @Chris - Yeah the DataType will depend on `new_MobileAppPassword`, which I guess is not `String`. Also, you need to debug and check why comparison is failing maybe because of some whitespaces.

Comment: Hi Rahul. Yes, the password was string.